# simulate the landing gear up and down in google earth

Tags: c#, google-earth-plugin

I am using google earht plugin in c# to simulate the flight of an aircraft, I can import a aircraft model(in dae format) into the google earth, but how can I simulate the up and down of the landing gear?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am so sorry I didn't make myself clear. I had import a 3D model(an aircraft) into google earth via geplugin in c#, now I can control the model as a whole(such as set its attitude by calling model.getOrientation().set(heading, tilt, roll), but if I want to control part of the model( for example the landing gear of an aircraft), how can I do it? Thanks！

Answer (score 2):

You should read about Model animation in Google's documentation: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/time#animating .  There are some Q&As online as well regarding this.

Likely you will have to create multiple models with the landing gear progressively going from retracted to extended, and vice-versa.  Then using the TimeSpan mechanism to step through those models to simulate landing gear lowering and raising.

I'm not sure how seamless you'll be able to achieve doing to a transition from a static model (plane in-flight) to a transitioning one (gear going up or gear going down).  GE is not well suited for this type of animation.  However some answers I see posted have achieved some success with this using the Google Earth Plug-in API.

However, you are aware I hope that the Google Earth Plugin API is being terminated by Google at the end of this year.  You may be wasting your time to create an elaborate aircraft simulation only to have it become useless in December of this year.

Comment: Thank you very much! If GE is not well suited for this type of animation, would you please give me a suggestion to find another solution? Thank you very much again.

Comment: I'm sorry, I personally don't know of any alternatives in particular to Google Earth, though I do use it extensively.